# Error when i try to use select 2 in rails 6

Tags: ruby-on-rails, jquery-select2, ruby-on-rails-6

I'm trying to use select2 in rails 6 by the gem select2-rails.

I already add in gemfile `gem "select2-rails"`
and run the `bundle` and `yarn add select2`
and inport on .js `require("select2")`
but when I try to use i get this error

```
$(...).select2 is not a function
```

how I slove this?

Comment: where did you right `require('select2')` .  i think you don't need write `require(select2)` in any file if you are using yarn for managing packages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's are the steps which you can follow to setup `select2` in Rails 6:

1. Install Webpacker in your Rails project properly, per the project README. If you're starting with a Rails 6 app, this will be done by default.
2. Add both `jquery` and `select2`:

   ```
   yarn add jquery select2
   ```
3. Add a select box to the DOM

   ```
   <select class="js-states" name="state">
     <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
      ...
     <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
   </select>
   ```
4. Import jquery, select2 and select2 css and apply to the select box when the page is loaded:

   ```
   import $ from 'jquery'
   import 'select2'
   import 'select2/dist/css/select2.css'

   window.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', () => {
     $('.js-states').select2()
   })
   ```
5. For development, set `compile: true` in `config/webpacker.yml`. Running the `webpack-dev-server` is optional.

For more you can also check this demo: https://github.com/rossta/rails6-webpacker-demo/compare/example/select2

Comment: worked when I remove jquery from environment.js

environment.plugins.append('Provide', new webpack.ProvidePlugin({
  $: 'jquery',
  jQuery: 'jquery'
}));